# StringBuilder not working as expected

Tags: java, mysql, stringbuilder

I'm having trouble with `StringBuilder` and I can't solve no matter what I do...

This is my code:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    tables[i][0] = rs.getString(3);
    tables[i][1] = tables[i][0].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + tables[i][0].substring(1);
    StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder(tables[i][1]);
    tables[i][1] = strb.insert(5, ' ').toString();
    tables[i][1] = strb.insert(6, Character.toUpperCase(tables[i][1].charAt(6))).toString();
    tables[i][1] = strb.deleteCharAt(7).toString();
    tables[i][1] = strb.insert(tables[i][1].length() - 4, ' ').toString();

    for (int r = 0; r == tables[i][1].length() - 5; r++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(tables[i][1].charAt(r)) == true) {
            tables[i][1] = strb.insert(r, ' ').toString();
            if (Character.isDigit(tables[i][1].charAt(r + 1)) == false) {
                tables[i][1] = strb.insert(r + 1, ' ').toString();
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(tables[i][1]);
    i++;
}
System.out.println(i);
```

This while structure receives a `String` from a `ResultSet` like "`feiratest2abril2009`" which is the name of a table in my database. Everything works fine until the 8th row. When the program reaches the for loop in order to insert an empty space before the first digit found and after the last digit found it fails to do so.

The program prints `tables[i][1]` as "`Feira Test2abril 2009`" and I expected it to print "`Feira Test 2 abril 2009`"...

Does anyone have any idea why that's happening? Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: why are you using StringBuilder.insert rather than append?  specifying an index is getting you into trouble

Comment: `r == tables[i][1].length() - 5` is an unusual condition - this only runs if that array's length is 5, and then will run only once - in which case, why not make it a conditional instead of a loop?

Comment: Also, `if (condition == true)` is the same as `if (condition)`; similarly `if (condition == false)` is the same as `if (!condition)`.

Comment: But tables[i][1].length() should return me the String length as the variable stored in this position is a String shouldn't it?

Comment: But if I make it a conditional how could I tell the program where is the first number located as it can be anywhere?

Comment: You can keep it as a loop, you just need to change the guard condition to not be an equality.

Comment: as Andy said, this condition makes the loop run only once, try to replace r == tables[i][1].length() - 5 with r <= tables[i][1].length() - 5

Comment: Understood, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the loop condition:

```
for (int r = 0; r < tables[i][1].length() - 5; r++) {
```

And, when you find a digit, after inserting the spaces you also need to increment `r` to skip those spaces:

```
r += 2;
```

Comment: I've tried this already. For some reason the program won't even print the results if I change it to <. I'll try this, thank you.

Comment: See my update. Your program won't terminate if you don't increase r after inserting spaces. It will always find the same digit and keep inserting spaces until you run out of memory